# Creating users that belong to another user in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to create a simple blogging application with 2 user levels: "writer" and "manager"

Writers belongs to managers, and managers can have many writers.

Writers can only see their own posts, but managers can see all the posts that their writers make.

Now my question is, how should I implement this type of system?

I'm pretty sure I should be using Devise to generate user authentication. But should I be generating separate models for each type of user (writer or model) or should I generate a roles table instead?

I don't know if that's specific enough; I spent the day racking my head over this with no solution in sight, so if you need to know more please let me know and I'll answer in the comments. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a simple user table with `manager_id`.

```
create_table :users do |t|
  # ...other columns...

  t.integer :manager_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Returns all writers under this manager
  has_many :writers, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :manager_id

  # Returns this writer's manager
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => 'User'

  # Allows this user to be author of posts
  has_many :posts

  # Associates posts of all writers under this manager
  has_many :writers_posts, :through => :writers, :class_name => 'Post'

  # If user has no manager, she's a manager
  def manager?
    manager_id.nil?
  end

  # If user has a manager, she's a writer
  def writer?
    !manager?
  end
end
```

This allows you to do the following things with your user.

```
if @user.manager?
  @user.writers # => [<User>, <User>, ...]
  @user.writers_posts # => [<Post>, <Post>, ...]
end

if @user.writer?
  @user.manager # => <User>
end
```

This implementation determines whether a user is a manager or a writer simply by the presence of a manager. If a user has a manager, she must be a writer. Else, she's a manager. If this is not flexible enough you can add extra boolean columns specifying whether user is one, the other, or even both. Also note that this is simply a `User` model that has both writer and manager methods. So you *could* call `@writer.writers_posts` (which is not meant to be for a writer user), but you shouldn't.

### Authentication

Since all you have is a regular `User` model, you can follow any Devise tutorial to setup authentication for it. Both writers and managers are just users who simply login.

### Authorization

As far as permissions and post visibility, it all comes down to being able to call the above methods on your current user.

```
if current_user.manager?
  current_user.writers_posts.each do |post|
    # display post
  end
end
```

So frankly, CanCan is an overkill. All you need to do is add a few `before_filter` and a few `if current_user.manager?` conditions in your views. CanCan is more comprehensive, and on my experience it's too much in most apps.

Comment: one thing I want to know is; how would one sign up as a manager/writer using Devise? Do I add some sort of writer:boolean column? I'm not familiar with the `has_many :writers, :class_name => 'User'` part of your answer..

Comment: You will have to override devise controller with your own controller (see devise docs/examples). In your new controller you will have to either assign user as a writer to some existing manager user (this will make her a writer), or keep her unassigned to anyone (that will make her a manager). These are all just basic ActiveRecord associations, nothing more. Learn basics of rails.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still just a beginner to Rails and I know the basics but there's still a lot I need to know. I'm going through http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association to know more about this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following gem:

[CanCan for authorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) More info http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

For you user model you could have a column specifying the user role => manager or writer, and for each user you could have a manager_id column (when a user is manager you will put null here)

Edit: You should use Devise too, for authentication

Comment: Hi Paul, yeah, I've watched that particular Railscast already, but I'm not sure exactly how to apply it. I'm not sure whether he's using a separate model for his roles. Plus I need the writer to actually belong to a manager account.

I'm thinking something like polymorphic associations in conjunction with Devise....

Comment: Cancan might be what I'm looking for, I just saw this: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use devise and you should implement an admin role for the managers that has access to all the posts.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role provides instructions on how to do this.

Comment: @AlexLockwood lol k, i accepted that other guy's answer just because he put it first

Comment: and sorry for being a douche about the "homework" question. I answer so many StackOverflow questions everyday and about 75% of them are little-to-no effort questions but ya, I don't think you were cheating.

Comment: It's the [hottest question](http://oi45.tinypic.com/aoovow.jpg) on stackexchange. :) By the way, I edited your question a tiny bit so people will stop voting to close it... they say it's "off topic" lol. But it's not! OK, but seriously... I'm done right now... I won't look at the thread for the rest of the day. Enjoy the reputation :P

Comment: You'll have a gold badge pretty soon :P

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer from hakunin, but I think he's missing something from the user model.  I think there needs to be a "source" called out, otherwise there will be a "stack level too deep" error.

```
# Associates posts of all writers under this manager
has_many :writers_posts, :through => :writers, :class_name => 'Post', :source => :posts
```